# org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

plz help me to solve this error

> message org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse
>   configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
>
> description Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne qui l''a empêché
>   de satisfaire la requête.

exception

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:365)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:233)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:557)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
cause mère

org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2246)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2158)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2137)
    imagesrdf.ws.imagesrdf.webservice.util.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:23)
    imagesrdf.ws.imagesrdf.webservice.dao.UserDAO.<init>(UserDAO.java:24)
    imagesrdf.ws.imagesrdf.webservice.services.usrService.<init>(usrService.java:64)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:82)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.POJOResourceFactory.createResource(POJOResourceFactory.java:43)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:215)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
cause mère

org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 2 of document  : La cible de l'instruction de traitement correspondant à "[xX][mM][lL]" n'est pas autorisée. Nested exception: La cible de l'instruction de traitement correspondant à "[xX][mM][lL]" n'est pas autorisée.
    org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2238)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2158)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2137)
    imagesrdf.ws.imagesrdf.webservice.util.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:23)
    imagesrdf.ws.imagesrdf.webservice.dao.UserDAO.<init>(UserDAO.java:24)
    imagesrdf.ws.imagesrdf.webservice.services.usrService.<init>(usrService.java:64)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:82)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.POJOResourceFactory.createResource(POJOResourceFactory.java:43)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:215)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show your hibernate.cfg.xml and mention which Jboss version.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
      
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <!-- sql dialect-->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <!-- db connection setting-->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rdfimagesws</property>

Comment: <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="password" /> 
    <!-- all executed sql statement to stdout-->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    
    <!-- entities classes-->
    <mapping class="imagesrdf.ws.imagesrdf.webservice.model.User"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

Comment: You can edit your question and it's a lot easier to see code when they are formatted, than when they are in a single line in comments. Increases your chances of getting an answer quick.

Answer (score 0):

The exception stack trace shows `org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 2 of document`

And from the comments,the second line in the cfg.xml file is

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "hibernate.sourceforge.net/…;
```

That doesn't seem like a valid xml. Are you sure you wrote that XML or is it copied from somewhere? Try fixing the xml and run the application again.